# Cyclic Dependencies detected while creating exe from rcp plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a bunch of eclipse plugins projects. Everything works fine when I run them from eclipse but when I try to create exe from the plugins I get the following error

**A cycle was detected when generating the classpath Plugin A, Plugin B, Plugin C, Plugin D, Plugin B**

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means for example :

```
Plugin A has a dependency to plugin B
and
Plugin B has a dependency to plugin A
```

You need to refactor your code so that you don't have this problem anymore.
Try to determine which code/plugin is overused, and optimize the distribution, even if that means havings some code duplicate.

And before that, try cleaning your project or restart eclipse, we never know...